# 2003 Honda Civic battery won't stay charged

Tags: honda, civic, battery-drain

My 2003 Honda Civic sometimes won't start. It will start with a Jump, and then may be fine for a couple of weeks, or a couple of days. This has been going on for a while. The Starter and battery are new, and the alternator tests fine. Everything checks out fine in the charging system. It's like once in a while something drains the battery very fast. Last Friday, I replaced the battery. I drove the car all weekend, I had auto zone check the charging system, and it was fine. I drove the car to school on Monday, and it wouldn't start at lunch until I got someone to jump it. I took it to another auto parts store and everything tested fine. Does anyone have any ideas? Also, every now and then all my gauges stop working for a couple of minutes.I don't know if that is related.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! If the battery, starter, and alternator check out fine, the only thing left is the wiring. I'd suggest there's a wire which has a poor connection, be it the ground or the positive lead. My '03 Civic did this once. The entire car went dead when I tried to start it. I wiggled one of the main wires to the battery (don't remember which, but think it was the positive) and it started right up. That was three weeks ago and I've not had it do the same thing again (but fully expect it to happen in the future).

Comment: Auto parts store battery and alternator tester are not very reliable.  You’re fortunate to get an employee that knows how to configure either a battery or alternator for a test. And even if you do that; as I’ve seen on 2 occasions, 1 test say alternator is good and 1 said it’s failed.

Answer (score 1):

you have a bad battery cable.  Most likely the ground wire.  The next time it doesn't start, have someone wiggle around on the wiring while you try starting it.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a parasitic draw which is slowly using battery power up when car id off-suggest a parasitc draw test